# How to display the Group name field in continuous pages in Crystal Report?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have created one crystal report which has one Group name field too. My Crystal report has 3 pages. But the Group Name field is displayed only in the first page. I want to display the Group Name field in the next pages also. Any one help me.
I am using Crystal Reports 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the group name field in group header section and check "Repeat group header in each page" in group options (available via group expert).